# Number of Subgames in Asymmetric Signaling Game

Tags: game-theory

In a two player, two signal  asymmetric information signaling game, *how many subgames are there?* The sender moves first, the receiver does not see the sender type, but responds to the observed signal with one of two actions?

My assumption would be a total of 7 subgames. One for the entire game, one for each sender type, and one for each of the four nodes where the receiver interprets the signal.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Showing the game tree would help.